# How to organize swift source code in pattern?

Tags: ios, swift3

I have some codes in java which organized well, so it helps me manage source code as well as extend in future easily. These codes as follow

```
public interface IDataModel<T extends IDataModel> {
    void copyData(T data);
    long getUpdatedTime();
}


public abstract class AbstractDataModel<T extends IDataModel> implements IDataModel<T>{
  protected long updatedTime;

  public long getUpdatedTime(){
    return updatedTime;
  }
}

public class concreteDataA extends AbstractDataModel<concreteDataA>{
  String property1;

  public String getProperty1(){
    return property1;
  }

  @override
  public void copyData(concreteDataA data){
    property1 = data.getProperty1();
    updatedTime = data.getUpdatedTime();
  }
}
```

Now i want to port into iOS swift 3.0. Is it possible to organize code in swift 3.0 as above? Or is there any equivalent way in swift to organize code as above? I'm quite new to swift iOS, so it makes me hard to organize source code in pattern. Thanks you.

Comment: Yes, it is possible but in general Swift has much better ways to organise code than Java, mainly because of extensions and better abstraction using protocols. You can't create an abstract class but you can add a default implementation for protocol methods.

Comment: What do mean by 'organize', indentation? control + i, in Xcode will indent your code correctly.

Comment: Thank @Sulthan, Can you please give me a sample of code in swift that equivalent as above?

Comment: @MichaelP No. Try yourself first. Also, your example is incomplete.

Comment: @Sulthan Ok, thank you. But of course i tried myself, but it seems i'm not get Swift well, that why i asked here.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't provided much in the way of context, but it seems like you're struggling developing a "protocol-oriented" solution, as Swift folks like to call the pattern. Here are a couple of options that might solve your problem (spoiler – I think the problem is in your design):

## Interface: Protocol, Abstract Class: Protocol Extension

Like [@sulthan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669586/sulthan) mentioned, you can certainly get to a similar place using protocols with default implementations, like so:

```
protocol DataModel {
    mutating func copy(data: Self)
    var updatedTime : Float { get }
}

extension DataModel {
    var updatedTime : Float { return 0 }
}
```

However, you'll run into a problem when you try to implement the `ConcreteDataModel` since you want to specialize it to account for the `property1` value that isn't mentioned in the protocol. Your options are to relax that requirement in `ConcreteDataModel` (aka don't do that) or use typecasting. *Please note*, fighting the typing system in Swift is a sure sign that your code is not idiomatic! You should see this difficulty as the language nudging you to reconsider your approach.

## Use immutable data types

This is the most straight-forward answer. If what you've described above is actually a concrete example from your app, then you don't really need protocols at all. (In fact, your Java implementation is certainly over-abstracting.) Swift `struct`s are immutable, which means that whenever you change them, you are actually changing a copy.

```
struct DataModel {
    let updatedTime: Float

    mutating func update(time: Float) {
        self = DataModel(updatedTime: time)
    }
}

var data1 = DataModel(updatedTime: 3)
var data2 = data1
data2.update(time: 17)
print(data1.updatedTime)  // 3.0
print(data2.updatedTime)  // 17.0
```

## Model your behavior apart from your data

This is the generalized solution. From a design perspective, it's clear that you have two distinct concerns. You want something copyable, and you want something that tracks "time." Why not just let your code reflect that?

```
protocol Copier {
    associatedtype Data
    func copy(from: Data) -> Data
}

protocol Clock {
    var time: Float { get }
}

class AlarmClock: Clock, Copier {
    let time: Float
    let alarm: Float

    init(time: Float, alarm: Float) {
        self.time = time
        self.alarm = alarm
    }

    func copy(from: AlarmClock) -> AlarmClock {
        return AlarmClock(time: from.time, alarm: from.alarm)
    }
}
```

Of course, you could even go the last step and provide the default implementation for `Clock.time` if you really needed it.